# Mac creating files w/ wrong perms on samba share

Tags: permissions, samba, osx-snow-leopard

In my group, which is very heterogeneous in terms of machines, we use a samba share to collaborate on files and such.  In all but one case, it works as expected (or at least close enough).

The one exception is my boss' laptop, a snow leopard macbook air.  On his desktop (also snow leopard), if he creates a file it ends up serverside with perms of 774, but when he creates it with the Air, the perms are 644.  The key problem is the lack of group write permission on the laptop created files.  What's really confusing is that everything that I've looked at on the two machines are identical - same version of OS X, same version of samba (3.0.25b-apple), same settings for the same software, etc.  I can't imagine why one machine would be different than the other, but it is.

To try to be complete w/ the description, here is the relevant portion of my smb.conf file:

```
comment = my Share
path = /path/to/share
public = no
writeable = yes
printable = no
force group = myshare
directory mask = 0770
create mask = 0770
force create mode = 0770
force directory mode = 0770
```

EDIT:  I looked at three more Macs and all of them worked as expected which leaves this one laptop the true oddball.  This wasn't as good as a test as the others though, as they were all leopard.

Answer (score 4):

try setting

```
unix extensions = off
```

in your globals, more details at [apple's forums](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7349655)

Comment: But how would that explain the two Macs which are (supposedly) configured identically behaving differently here?

Comment: The umasks are confirmed the same on both machines?

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought but everything I can look at are the same.  I'm a bit leery of turning off the unix extensions as we had that a long while ago and it caused problems w/ the linux users.  Also, see edit - 3 more Macs (all leopard though) are also fine, so this one is really an oddball.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same effect as turning off "unix extensions" on the server by using a "smb://" rather than "cifs://" URL when connecting.