# setgid on samba share not working with Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, samba, permissions, setgid

I've set the setgid-bit on folders within my samba-share. It works like a charm for windows and linux clients.

Accessing such a folder with a mac-client the setgid is ignored and the group permission of the newly created files/directories is set to the current users default group.

I've tried the the setting `unix extensions = no` mentioned on this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/104341/mac-creating-files-w-wrong-perms-on-samba-share) but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to force the created files in a share to always belong to a certain group  is to use the `force group = groupname` option in the share configuration in smb.conf. If you want to make sure that only users who already belong to that group can create files use a + sign in front of the group name: `force group = +groupname`.

More info on the samba manual for [smb.conf](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html)